# How to convert gson to json in node js?

Tags: node.js, json, gson

I want to change the gson data to json data in node js, is there a way?

sample data gson
like this

`["test","{\"ID\":0}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/gson

```
npm install gson
```

Code sample:

```
const GSON= require('gson');

const gsonObj = GSON.decode('["test","{\\"ID\\":0}]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything special. You must first define or create a correct format of the object. That your example is not the right format, and it is not JSON. Then with the following command

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("[{\"brand\":\"Jeep\", \"doors\": 3}, {\"brand\":\"Jeep\", \"doors\": 3}]"));
```

And if your format is incorrect, you will encounter this error when converting to JSON

> undefined:1 ["test","{"ID":0}]
>              ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 11
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object. (/home/test1.js:24:18)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:868:12)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11

Answer (score 0):

Is that the JSON string? i didnt see backtick on the first and last.
If yes, you just need to convert that to JSON object like :

```
let jsonString = `
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 25,
    "tag": ["javascript", "express", "nuxt"]
  }
`

let jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString)
console.log(jsonObj)
```

Comment: JSON is not the same as GSON